# Use existing ExpressJS app as Firebase app

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, webserver

I have existing app that runs on Heroku. It's a simple web app with no background jobs or database.

Basically it has three endpoints. One of them serves the HTML, the other is `POST` endpoint for communicating with backend and third is `GET` endpoint that renders error HTML content as well.

Now the frontend is not single page application and the goal is not to be one. It's just HTML page with a form and some links. The front end can be used without Javascript.

My questions are:

1. Can I re-use existing ExpressJS code? I was thinking about importing route callbacks and use them inside the "functions".
2. I know there is Firebase hosting that can serve static content. However, as I mentioned the server can respond with HTML content so I'd need traditional routing (such as `/error` url for rendering HTML error). In my ExpressJS app I use `.ejs` templating so I'd like to load the template and render it.
3. Can Firebase be set up so the "backend" (functions) can be placed on my own domain? I'd like to call relative URLs from my index file (like that `POST` endpoint) instead of using Google Firebase URL.

I'm really just trying to find out if my use case can fit the Firebase infrastructure. I think it's a good candidate since I need the web app to respond infrequently and it's not really demanding, not many people would use it. This is also my hobby project so I'm trying to minimize costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes you can, but keep in mind some things are limited. In my case, I had tried to use `multer` library for multipart forms but didn't work and had to resort to using `busboy` instead. To use an Express app for a function endpoint, you simply just pass your `app` as the `onRequest` function parameter like so: `functions.https.onRequest(app)`.

   Docs:
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps
2. The hosting is for static files only. You can't use that with `.ejs`. Unless, you're thinking to use that as a proxy to your Express app..
3. Yes, you can set custom domains so you can use your domain(s) instead of default ones. Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

   > 1. From your project's Hosting page, enter the wizard for connecting a custom domain:
   >
   >    - If you have only one Hosting site, click Connect domain.
   >    - If you have more than one Hosting site, click View for the desired site, then click Connect domain.
   > 2. Enter the custom domain name that you'd like to connect to your Hosting site.
   > 3. (Optional) Check the box to redirect all requests on the custom domain
   >      to a second specified domain (such that yourdomain.com and
   >      www.yourdomain.com redirect to the same content).
   > 4. Click Continue to initiate the validation process.